# Simulating a web navigation with Ruby

Tags: ruby, forms, post, web, simulate

I'm trying to simulate an user filling a form and submiting it with ruby.
I heard it was possible with some test framework when you test your own application (eg : testing a rails app).

What I want to do is :
- open a webpage where there's a form.
- fill the form
- submit the form

Is there any magic gem to do so, or do I need to parse the page and use a post request with arguments ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you Webrat or Capybara. Capybara uses embedded webkit engine written in Qt, so you don't need any browser to test your application.

https://github.com/brynary/webrat

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: Thanks, but these are test framework... is it acceptable to use it, even if I'm not testing anything ? ;-)

Comment: These are not test frameworks, rspec and cucumber are test frameworks. These are only browser simulators. You can use them without testing any result...

Answer (score 1):

try to use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

Also, you can use it with Cucumber or RSpec